# What is the best and most reliable way to call other templates into page.php in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

My Wordpress website uses two push menus, both of which I initially had situated in the `header.php` file. It wasn't until I started needing to use a lot of PHP code in one of these menus that I decided to have them in separate files and call them into the page structure via PHP commands. Ive been wondering what would be the best way of going about this and would appreciate any advice on whether I'm doing it correctly. Below is the code from the simpler of the two menus – I've saved this as `mobile-menu.php`.

```
 <div class="mobile-menu">

        <nav class="main-menu" id="mobile">

            <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'header' ) ); ?>

        </nav>

 </div>
```

This isn't a particularly long list of code, but the other menu (`shopping-basket.php`)is a lot longer as it uses PHP from a plugin I've installed, and I don't want masses of code in my header.

I've then called both menus into my `page.php` using "include" commands, like I have with the header and footer – for example:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<?php include("mobile-menu.php"); ?>

<?php include("shopping-basket.php"); ?>
```

Is this recommended? It seems to work okay, but I've noticed that despite saving the files as PHP templates with a `.php` extension, they're showing up as HTML files when I have a look in my FTP account. Why would this be?

Any advice or info would be appreciated as I can't really find any concrete info on this online and have got to the stage that I'm at by searching through forums etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would be best off using `get_template_part()` instead of `include()`.

> Load a template part into a template

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_part/

You should put the contents of `mobile-menu.php` into `templates/menu-mobile.php` (Note that I've reordered the name for least- to most- specific) and `templates/shoppingbasket.php`. Call them as so:

```
get_template_part('templates/menu','mobile');
get_template_part('templates/shoppingbasket');
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the info. I forgot to mention in my question that I'm not using a child theme, I'm using my own very basic theme that I've made from scratch – will this have any effect on the outcome? I've not got a templates folder yet, should I create one if I'm not using a child theme, or just have them loose with all the other files like `header.php` and `functions.php`?

Comment: I do this with themes from scratch as well. I find it best to make a `templates` directory and put the templates in there.